# Stats about askers and answerers in Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions, statistics

How can I get the statistics data of how many people ask questions and how many answer here? I'm curious about the distributions and seeing if more people ask than answer.

Comment: _"and seeing if more people ask than answer"_ That's naturally very likely.

Comment: You can get stats from the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1002008), you can run this query:

```sql
select 'questioners', count(distinct owneruserid) from posts where parentid is null and title is not null
union
select 'answerers', count(distinct owneruserid) from posts where parentid is not null
```

Running it for Meta Stack Exchange, I get:

- questioners: 24035
- answerers: 10888

Note that deleted users all have the same id: `null` and deleted posts are not listed in SEDE, so both of the numbers produced by the query are underestimates.